# How to add Parameters for Object using this way?

Tags: java

Note: I'm a Beginner/Intermediate lvl java programmer so please be nice :S

I came across this lesson about how to compare 2 objects and I noticed this way of creating an object/instance which is completely new to me.

```
 MyValueObject myValueObject = (MyValueObject) obj;
```

Q: How to put my parameters to pass it to the constructor for this object using this way?

What I'm used to and most of beginners too is:

```
 MyClass Object = new MyClass( my parameters ) ;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

That's not instantiation, it's called [casting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). It does not create a new object, but rather it uses `obj` as a `MyValueObject` object. It basically says that `obj` is really a `MyValueObject` and it can be used as one.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyValueObject myValueObject = (MyValueObject) obj;
```

doesn't create, but casts `obj` to a `MyValueObject`

Answer (score 0):

In that first section, you are just assigning a previously instantiated object to the myValueObject variable. The object is already constructed.